# Backbone templates doesn't update to new value

Tags: backbone.js, yeoman, ejs

I scaffolded a backbone app with Yeoman. I used the standard template .ejs. There is something strange happening. If I take an element form my HTML it will update to the standard .ejs `

your content here

When I edit my template however and reload, the new content will not be shown, and the old content is showed:

```
<p>your content here </p>
```

My code:

main.js

```
    /*global require*/
'use strict';

require.config({
    shim: {
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: [
                'underscore',
                'jquery'
            ],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'jquery'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
        backbone: '../bower_components/backbone/backbone',
        underscore: '../bower_components/underscore/underscore',
        bootstrap: '../bower_components/sass-bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'
    }
});

require([
    'backbone',
    'routes/app'
], function (Backbone, AppRouter) {
    var app = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

AppRouter (App.js);

```
/*global define*/

define([
    'jquery',
    'backbone',
    'views/wine',
    'views/headerView'
], function ($, Backbone, WineView, HeaderView) {
    'use strict';

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

        routes: {
            '' : 'doSomething'
        },

        doSomething: function() {
            console.log('doSomething init');
            var headerView = new HeaderView();
        }

    });

    return AppRouter;
});
```

And the HeaderView:

```
    /*global define*/

define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'templates'
], function ($, _, Backbone, JST) {
    'use strict';

    var HeaderViewView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: JST['app/scripts/templates/HeaderView.ejs'],

        tagName: 'div',

        id: '',

        className: '',

        events: {
            'click .new' : 'addNew'
        },

        initialize: function () {
            this.render();
        },

        render: function () {
            $('#header').append(this.template);
        }
    });

    return HeaderViewView;
});
```

HeaderView.ejs

```
<h1>New Text</h1>
```

Output website:

```
your content here
```

Comment: Have you tried a hard refresh (ctrl + F5) or even deleting your browser history and local files

Comment: Yes, same thing happens when I open an incognito file or new browser. 

I also made a whole new project without require.js using this tutorial: http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2014/03/command-line-backbone-yeoman/

same result: my templates are not updated.

Comment: can you `console.log(this.template);` in render function? or even better setup an environment which reproduce the problem?